# mapping :bnext and :bprevious throws error

Tags: vim, macvim

I have

```
nmap <leader>l :bnext<cr>
```

and

```
nmap <leader>h :bprevious<cr>
```

in my vimrc but when I try to use either mapping I get

> e492: Not an editor command: BufSurfBack

If I just use `:bnext` and `:bprevious` normally it works fine

I am using macvim if it makes a difference

any ideas?

Comment: Those mappings work correctly for me. Check `:map` to see if they have actually been bound as you expected.

Comment: `BufSurfBack` is a command that certainly comes from some plugin.

Comment: yes but not a plugin I have intentionally installed so I feel like it came with another one.  I havnt found my mappings in :map yet but I did find:bn and :bp mapped to :BufSurfForward<cr> and BufSurfBack<cr> respectively which again work if I use them but fail if I try to map them with the mappings in the op

Comment: yeah just found them in  :map so they appear to be getting mapped correctly

Comment: this seems to be the plugin https://github.com/ton/vim-bufsurf but its not in my bundle folder

Comment: well, *you* installed it at some point. Do you use sessions? They can be very nasty when you tinker with your config.

Comment: Honestly I didn't even know about sessions until you just mentioned them and I googled them so no I havn't been using.  Even if I did install the plugin why would I not be able to map some bindings to a command that works on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `:nmap` which allows for recursive mappings. Because of this, the first few characters in each mapping (e.g. `:bp`) are triggering the plugin functions BufSurfForward and BufSurfBack.

Try using `nnoremap` instead of `nmap` which will disallow any recursive mappings.

Also, if you don't use the plugin defining the BufSurfForward and BufSurfBack, you could uninstall that plugin.